# d3 how to make single stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, var

I'm trying to get d3 to draw a single stacked bar chart, like so:

```html
<svg width = '500' height= '100'>
<rect x='0' y='0' width='224' height='30' fill='green'/>
<rect x='224' y='0' width='84' height='30' fill='blue'/>
<rect x='308' y='0' width='29' height='30' fill='darkgray'/>
<rect x='337' y='0' width='3' height='30' fill='#606060'/>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the x position starts at zero, then each subsequent x position is equal to the sum of the preceding widths.

So I'm trying to get d3 to draw something like that from an array called datavars:

```
var datavars = [224, 84, 29, 3];
```

... and to ensure that d3 assigns the correct width-value to the correct x-value, I created these variables:

```
var prev_width0 = 0;
var prev_width1 = datavars[0];
var prev_width2 =  datavars[0] +  datavars[1];
var prev_width3 =  datavars[0] +  datavars[1] +  datavars[2];
```

... and define the x value like so:

```
//create SVG element
var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', w)
.attr('height', h);

svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(datavars)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('width', function(d){
    return d;})
               .attr('x',function(d, i){
               return 'prev_width'+i; })
.attr('y',0)
.attr('height', 30);
```

As you might have guessed, the strongly-indented function (based on the sum of the preceding widths, and defined in the `prev_width` variables) returns a string for each iteration (prev_width0, prev_width1, etc.) and **not** the values I thought I defined when I created the `prev_width` variables.

I'm obviously defining the variables incorrectly. Any idea how I can do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not interpret the string `"datavars1"` as the variable `datavars1`. To interpret a string as a JavaScript variable you can use `eval()`. So change: `return 'prev_width'+i; })` to `return eval('prev_width'+i); })`. Although a better idea might be to use an array instead such as:

```
var prev_width = [0,
                  datavars[0],
                  datavars[0] +  datavars[1],
                  datavars[0] +  datavars[1] +  datavars[2]
                 ];

...
   .attr('x',function(d, i){
   return prev_width[i]; })
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c5eqrp3/1/)

You can do a similar thing with the colors:

```
var colors = ['green','blue','darkgray','#606060'];

...
.attr('fill', function(d, i){ return colors[i]; })
```

[**Bar chart with color**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c5eqrp3/2/)

You can also create a single array of objects to store the color, width, etc.

---

A more scalable idea would be to get rid of the array `prev_width` and have a function that can take the sum up to a point. Such as:

```
function sum(array, start, end) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i=start; i<end; i++) total += array[i];
    return total;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
...
   .attr('x',function(d, i){
   return sum(datavars, 0, i); })
```

[**Example using summation**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c5eqrp3/3/)

Comment: ah... these are very nice, thanks a million. Your first suggestion is what I was struggling towards, and the next few are so much more elegant. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet (approached a little differently by me)

```js
//this function deals with pairing finding x for each width in the array and add them to a new array called x_and_width_values
//example :[[0,224],[84,224],[29,308],[3,337]]
//           ^  ^    ^   ^    ^   ^    ^  ^
//          x width  x  width  .............
function combinations(prev,current,index,arr){
// This method focus on accummulating results by reference previous and current element
//for the first and second element we need specifically add this
if(index==1){
x_and_width_values.push([arr[index-1],0]);
x_and_width_values.push([arr[index],prev])
}
//other elements we use index as follows;
else{
x_and_width_values.push([arr[index],prev])
}
return prev+current
}
//after creating an array with all [x,width] combination, we map it to colors to get out final array
//example :[[[0,224],'green'],[[84,224],'blue'],[29,308],[[3,337],'darkgray']
function colors_with_combination(e, i) {
    return [x_and_width_values[i], colors[i]];
   }

//*******************acutal beef og code***************
var x_and_width_values=[];
//this link is needed to creation of svg elements
var link="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
//all your widths
var all_widths=[224,84,29,3];
//all your colors
var colors=['green','blue','darkgray','#606060'];
//sort your width array to be on the safe side
all_widths.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
//find all width and x  combination
all_widths.reduce(combinations);
//map width and x values to color values
var all = x_and_width_values.map(colors_with_combination);
//create a  loop for object creation
for(var i=0;i<all.length;++i){
var rect=document.createElementNS(link,'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS(null,'x',all[i][0][1])
rect.setAttributeNS(null,'width',all[i][0][0]);
rect.setAttributeNS(null,'fill',all[i][1]);
rect.setAttributeNS(null,'height','30');
rect.setAttributeNS(null,'y','0');
document.getElementById('svg').appendChild(rect);;
}
```

```html
<svg id='svg' width = '500' height= '100'>
</svg>
```